# Template typename reuse when declared in member variables

Tags: c++, class, templates

Suppose I have the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct Task
{
    T* item;
    Task* next;
    int priority;
};

class PriorityQueue
{
    public:
        PriorityQueue();
        Enqueue(T* item, int priority);
        T* Dequeue();

    private:
        Task<T>* head;

};
```

The above code will throw a compilation error where **T is not declared in the PriorityQueue class**. If I would like to refer to the T* item which is defined as a template class in the Task struct, what would be the proper syntax to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` does not have special meaning. Each template class or template method must be declared to be a template, using the syntax `template<typename T>` or variations of it. The two `T`s will not automatically be the same in this case.

When you use a template class, you need to specify what the template arguments are, with the syntax `classname<SomeType>`. As @Antonio Garrido points out; in your case that likely means that your head member should be declared as `Task<T>* head;`

Now, as it seems that `Task` is not part of the interface, you can also declare it as part of the PriorityQueue class. That way `T`:

```
template<typename T>
class PriorityQueue
{    
  struct Task
  {
    T* item;
    Task* next;
    int priority;
  }

  public:
    PriorityQueue();
    Enqueue(T* item, int priority);
    T* Dequeue();

  private:
    Task* head;
};
```

You then use the template class:

```
PriorotyQueue<int> que;
auto que = PriorotyQueue<int>(); // alternatively   
que.Engueue(3);
```

Comment: In my first implementation, it seems that PriorityQueue class will not be able to find the T template I defined in Task struct. How would I do so?

Comment: @Mantracker. By using the second version.. (?!) I Don't follow.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I edited the question to be much clearer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that way 1 would work, unless you linked in something named T. and also, you need `;` after your class declarations.

As far as whether the two T's are the same, they're not. The whole point of Templates is that it allows you to have two types that are "kinda" the same but have different types. they are only the same in that they have the same interface.

I could do something like this in one single program:

```
PriorityQueue<std::string> stringQueue;

PriorityQueue<int> intQueue;
```

and I would have two different types of queues. `stringQueue` is of type `PriorityQueue<std::string>` and `intQueue` is of type `PriorityQueue<int>`. these are actually different types that share the same interface, because the C++ compiler will compile two different binaries for each. if I did something like:

```
intQueue.enqueue(5, 0);
stringQueue.enqueue("hello world", 1);
```

then `stringQueue` would contain a single `Task` of type `Task<string>`, because when `PriorityQueue<std::string>::enqueue` makes a new `Task` it makes a `Task<std::string` and the same with `intQueue` and integers.

T is just a variable which is conventional, but you can also do templates like this:

```
template<typename Type>
template<typename A>       //these two are basically the same as T
template<Task SpecialTask> //here SpecialTask would have to be a 
                           //Task or a child of Task
template<class C>          //C must be a class
template<typename T, U, V> //here are three templates in one declaration
template<PriorityQueue PQ,
         Task T,
         typename U>       //three of different "lineage"
```

so How does the compiler know that a `PriorityQueue<int>` should have `Task<int>` attributes? well it happens when it notices that it has a template attribute, or it is newing a template, and then it goes and compiles up binaries for `Task<int>` if it didn't have any already.

Answer (score 0):

The last line is

```
Task<T>* head;
```

By the way, you need to add ';' to end the struct/class definition

Comment: Thank you for the corrections, I corrected the code